# Returning the same type from abstract trait method

Tags: scala, typeclass, traits, abstract-type

Lets say we have a trait, that has some values and some operations on them.

```
trait Foo {
  type Self <: Foo
  val x: Int
  def withX(x: Int): Self
}
```

This is implemented using abstract types. We have a type bound on Self and can implement it like this:

```
case class Foo1(x: Int) extends Foo {
  type Self = Foo1
  def withX(x: Int) = copy(x = x)
}
```

That is fine. We can use the method and we see that the type is statically kept.

```
scala> Foo1(10).withX(5)
res0: Foo1 = Foo1(5)
```

Problems start when we want to have an operation with trait type, not the concrete type:

```
object Foo {
//Error:(13, 43) type mismatch;
//found   : f.Self
//required: A
//  def setFive[A <: Foo](f: A): A = f.withX(5)
}
```

Well, we can't quite do it, because the compiler does not know what type Foo#Self will be assigned to. But we know it is the same type.

Of course using an ugly approach works fine:

```
object Foo {
  // Ugly type signature
  def setFiveValid[A <: Foo](f: A): A#Self = f.withX(5)

  // Another ugly type signature
  def setFiveValid2[A <: Foo](f: A): f.Self = f.withX(5)
}
```

Neither of them express intent very clearly.

We can work around it using typeclasses though.

```
case class Foo2(x: Int)

trait FooOps[A] extends Any {
  def a: A
  def withX(x: Int): A
}

object Foo2 {
  implicit class Foo2Ops(val a: Foo2) extends AnyVal with FooOps[Foo2] {
    def withX(x: Int) = a.copy(x = x)
  }
}

object Foo {
  // View bounds approach.
  def setFiveValid3[A <% FooOps[A]](f: A): A = f.withX(5)
}
```

However this is still very noisy.

Is there a better way to implement `setFive`?

**Edit 1**

The main issue with self types are things like this:

```
Error:(24, 11) type mismatch;
 found   : app.models.world.WObject.WorldObjUpdate[self.Self] => app.models.world.WObject.WorldObjUpdate[self.Self]
    (which expands to)  app.models.game.events.Evented[(app.models.world.World, self.Self)] => app.models.game.events.Evented[(app.models.world.World, self.Self)]
 required: app.models.world.WObject.WorldObjUpdate[self.Self] => app.models.game.events.Evented[(app.models.world.World, Self)]
    (which expands to)  app.models.game.events.Evented[(app.models.world.World, self.Self)] => app.models.game.events.Evented[(app.models.world.World, Self)]
          identity
          ^
```

Which then resort to weird looking signatures and boilerplate again:

```
  def attackReachable(
    data: WObject.WorldObjUpdate[Self]
  ): WObject.WorldObjUpdate[data.value._2.Self]
```

Answer (score 5):

You could go down the "F-bounded quantification" road:

```
trait Foo[F <: Foo[F]] {
  def withX(x: Int): F
}

object Foo {
  def setFive[F <: Foo[F]](f: F): F = f.withX(5)
}
```

I used this a lot with success, but it comes at the price of having to write `F <: Foo[F]]` everwhere.

Comment: Yeah, that's not much cleaner, I forgot to mention I was trying to avoid that. Basically I'm searching for a solution with least amount of boilerplate.

Comment: Good luck with your search, I must warn you though; I have tried all the other scenarios, you don't get far without the "closed loop" that this approach provides. Type projections without the loop will make it impossible to do much with the return types.

Answer (score 1):

The best signature is the path-dependent type that you suggested:

```
// Another ugly type signature
def setFiveValid2[A <: Foo](f: A): f.Self = f.withX(5)
```

You don't even need the type parameter. Typing `f` as `Foo` will do (unless you need `A` for something else in your real context):

```
def setFiveValid3(f: Foo): f.Self = f.withX(5)
```

This is not ugly. It's one of the perfect uses for path-dependent types, on the contrary. I also disagree when you say that it doesn't express the intent clearly: you're clearly stating that the result will have the type `Self` of the argument that you're giving.